# changeTab Function with jquery

Tags: javascript, logic, shopify

Hi there community i managed to create that code that works as tabs function. Every tab has a collection that change with click on other tab, every collection if has more than 4 products it shows some button like "see all". I need to add that on the function changeTab. Here is the code i create;

```js
tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".featured-products-section__tab");
tabContents = document.querySelectorAll(".featured-products-section__products");
tabViewAll = document.querySelectorAll(".featured-products-section__view-all");

tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
  tab.addEventListener("click", function () {

    contentId = this.dataset.contentId;
    content = document.getElementById(contentId);

    tabContents.forEach(function (content) {
      content.classList.remove("active");
    });

    tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
      tab.classList.remove("active");
    });

    this.classList.add("active");
    content.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.featured-products-section__view-all.active {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.featured-products-section__view-all {
    display: none;
}
```

I create a new var called tabViewAll to get that button, but where i have to add it?
i tried some ways but unfortunatly no one worked.

Comment: Please add your html to your snippet so that it actually works.

Comment: @LeeTaylor i dont have html code cause its shopify site, it just need to add to the function that button (because it is content inside each tab).  You can check that section at bottom page: https://5lt6o3ix4p60vrma-53196980409.shopifypreview.com/collections/anillos-hombre